# How do I return an Observable to an outer promise in Effects of NgRX?

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, observable, ngrx

I have a question of how to return an Observable to an outer promise. I have in my effects.ts the following:

```
  @Effect()
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.LOGIN),
    switchMap((action: UserActions.LoginAction) => {

      this.db.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.payload.email, action.payload.password).then(data => {
        this.db.auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(reply => {
          return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/login', { token: reply }).subscribe(response => {
              if (response['valid'] === 'true') {
                localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(reply));
                this.router.navigate(['dash']);
              }
            });
        });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('signIn failed: ' + err.message);
      });
    })
  );
```

Now, my goal overall is to simply log in to FireBase to be able to grab an ID token and submit a post request to the back-end. If the response comes back with the property valid "true" then proceed to navigate to the "dash" module.

However, my problem is:

> Argument of type '(action: UserActions.LoginAction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: LoginAction, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.ts(2345)

I believe it is because I put my return statement within an outer promise. But I don't know how to make it return properly because Firebase uses promises, and NgRX uses Observables! I am trying to return an Observable from within a promise... thank you

Comment: firstly there are promises and secondly you do not return an action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @Effect()
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.LOGIN),
    switchMap((action: UserActions.LoginAction) =>
      from(this.db.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.payload.email, action.payload.password)),
    ),
    // switchMapTo(from(this.db.auth.currentUser.getIdToken())),
    switchMapTo(from(this.db.authState.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((user)=>{
        if (user)
          return from(user.getIdToken());
        else
          return of(null);
      })
    ))),
    switchMap(token => this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/login', { token: token })),
    tap((response: any) => {
      if (response.valid === 'true') {

        console.log("effects success");

        // localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
        this.router.navigate(['dash']);
      }
    }),
    map(response => new UserActions.LoginSuccessAction({ response }))//,
    // catchError(error => new UserActions.LoginFailureAction({ error }))
  );
```

After doing some serious research, I coded the correct answer. Thanks to Chris for his contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You must return an action after calling api

```
  @Effect()
  login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.LOGIN),
    switchMap((action: UserActions.LoginAction) =>
      from(this.db.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.payload.email, action.payload.password)),
    ),
    switchMapTo(from(this.db.auth.currentUser.getIdToken())),
    switchMap(token => this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/api/login', { token })),
    tap((response: any) => {
      if (response.valid === 'true') {
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
        this.router.navigate(['dash']);
      }
    }),
    map(response => UserActions.LoginSuccess({ response })),
    catchError(error => UserAction.LoginError({ error })),
  );
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null.
It appears db.auth.currentUser is null in this situation, and must db.authState must be used somehow to first determine the user?

Comment: @devteam6 what are the login steps?

Comment: I think I should be using authState to get the current user. Then from the user you get from there, you can call getIdToken(), which returns a promise. I read from another post it should look like this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return from(user.getIdToken())
      }

Comment: So... first signInWithEmailAndPassword, then afAuth.authState.pipe returns a user.getIdToken, from there we http.post the token and wait for a response.valid=="true"

Comment: you solved? if not, you could create an example on stackblitz so I can help you

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely on the right track. I remember struggling with this type of thing when I first was learning RxJS.

A few things I want to point out:

1. Effects are supposed to return Actions. That's what the error message is saying. If you don't want an Action to be returned, then you have to make it: `@Effect({ dispatch: false })`. In this type of situation, though, you should definitely dispatch an Action at the end, something like: "User Successfully Logged In" with the User Token as the payload. Then you can store that in your state using the reducer. But if all you really want to do is navigate to `/dash` afterwards, then use the `{ dispatch: false }` parameter.
2. To convert a Promise to an Observable, use the `from` function inside the `rxjs` library. So you would wrap everything up to where you'd normally stick the `then` function: `from(this.db.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.payload.email, action.payload.password))`.
3. Avoid `switchMap` for this type of situation. It will lead to race conditions. Use `exhaustMap` instead. And then use one for each Promise. So it would end up looking something like:

   `@Effect()
        login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(UserActions.LOGIN),
       exhaustMap((action: UserActions.LoginAction) => 
       from(this.db.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(action.payload.email, 
       action.payload.password)),
       exhaustMap(data => 
           from(this.db.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()),
       exhaustMap(reply => {
             return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/login', { token: 
       reply }),
       map(response => {
                 if (response['valid'] === 'true') {
                   localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(reply));
                   this.router.navigate(['dash']);
                 }
               });
           });
         })
       })
     );`

Comment: don't use the map operator for side effects, use tap operator